# after change textbox IsReadOnly attr, can not input chinese

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

When `MouseDoubleClick` on textbox, it can edit and input, but can't input Chinese, when switch to other window(or click a winform textbox on the mainwindow) and turn back, it can input Chinese now.

demo:

https://img2018.cnblogs.com/q/22977/201904/22977-20190410130035963-221502838.gif

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled="True" InputMethod.PreferredImeState="On" MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

```
        private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
            txtBox.IsReadOnly = false;
        }
```

update: the code is work

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
            txtBox.IsReadOnly = false;

            InputMethod.SetIsInputMethodEnabled(txtBox , false);
            InputMethod.SetIsInputMethodEnabled(txtBox , true);
        }
```

Comment: it's a wpf usercontrol,and used in a Winform Application

Comment: Is it maybe just because the textbox doesn't have focus? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_FocusManager_SetFocusedElement_System_Windows_DependencyObject_System_Windows_IInputElement_

Comment: it's have focus and english char is inputed